# Salesforce1 Publisher Action Submit Button overwrite

Tags: apex, visualforce, approval-process, salesforce1-app

I created a object-specific publisher action, my objective is to submit the custom object on the redirected visualforce page.
It works fine to pass the object parameters to the visualforce page, but how can i use or overwrite the standard button??

By default the button is disabled

[image]

```
<button class="primaryButton cuf-publisherShareButton default uiBlock uiButton" accesskey="" disabled="disabled" type="button" data-aura-rendered-by="5:1853.28"><!----><span class=" label bBody truncate" dir="ltr" data-aura-rendered-by="8:1853.28">Submit</span><!----></button>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Working on Salesforce1 too, and I found that for you. I hope it's what you are looking for. Works perfectly for me. Here is [the source doc](http://foobarforce.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/df13chatterpublisheractionsandsalesforce1.pdf)

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/canvas/sdk/js/publisher.js'></script>
<script> 
    Sfdc.canvas.publisher.subscribe({name: "publisher.showPanel",
        onData:function(e) {
            Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({name:"publisher.setValidForSubmit", payload:"true"});
    }});
    Sfdc.canvas.publisher.subscribe({ name: "publisher.post",
        onData: function(e) {
            alert("call some remote action here");
            Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({ name: "publisher.close",
                payload:{ refresh:"true" }});
    }}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Have you any idea, how to use the publisher.setPayload to post a Chatter feed?

Answer (score 1):

Since the publisher.setPayload is only meant for canvas, I have been using a remote action to create a post on chatter and then just after the remote action i do a refresh, for a global action using a VF.

> Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({
>       name: "publisher.refresh",
>       payload: {
>         feed: true
>        }
>     });

maybe you have come across a better solution.